# How match only words connected by dots?

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match only the words that are connected to other words by dots. For example, in the below, I want to match "two", "three", "four" but *not* "one":

```
//match only "two" "three" and "four"
.one .two.three.four
```

How do I do that?

I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
(\w+)((\.(([^\.]+\w)+))+)
```

Comment: @AvinashRaj Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(?<=\.)(\w+)(?=\.\w+)|(?<=\w\.)(\w+)|(?<=\s)(\w+)(?=\.\w+)
```

Try this.See demo .

http://regex101.com/r/jT3pG3/20

For js only as lookbehind is not supported

```
(?=\.(\w+)\.\w+)|(?=\s(\w+)\.\w+)|(?=\w\.(\w+)\b)
```

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/jT3pG3/22

Just remove duplicate results as some groups might satisfy more than 1 condition.

Comment: I don't think it will work in javascript because look behind is not supported

Comment: @ArunPJohny its tagged as Php as well

Comment: Apologies. I need it in javascript. I included PHP because I thought I could just translate for JS, but that won't work. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
\S+\.\S+/i
```

Here's a site you can practice regex easily.
http://rubular.com/r/FguTt59e8E

Answer (score 0):

You could use this shorter regex maybe if the requirement is only that words been to be linked with a dot (i.e. there's no initial dot required before the first word of the chains of words):

```
(?=(\b\w+\b)(?=\.(\w+\b)(?!\.)|\.\w+))
```

Also does not give duplicate matches; so no filtering necessary; you only need to check for the 1st and 2nd submatch. 1st submatch will contain most of the words while the 2nd submatch will contain the last word of the chain.

Kind of heavy use of lookaheads, but I don't think there's a regex solution in JS without.

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/hH2aD9/1)

A possible alternative would be to match every chain of words linked by a dot and then split on dot...

```
var s = ".one .two.three.four  .one. one.two";
var reg = /\b\w+(?:\.\w+)+\b/g;
var count = 0
while ((m = reg.exec(s)) != null) {
    var words = m[0].split(".");
    console.log("Word chain " + count + ": " + words.join(",") + "\n");
    count++;
}
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/2cex3yfq/)

Comment: @DonRhummy This regex doesn't get duplicates; and the second method is simpler IMO